# django admin/options.py TypeError: 2 options needed, 3 given

Tags: python, django, typeerror

**Edit: I have posted the full traceback below, as requested.**

I needed some custom logic to happen before deleting a pages model, so I overloaded the delete() method. (I know this is bad form. I fixed it later, but it's important to express how I got into this mess)

With something like this:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do some stuff...
    super(Pages, self).delete()
```

Unfortunately, this caused the following TypeError when I tried to delete the page via the admin interface: ***delete_model() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given***

I decided that I needed to do things properly, and so I deleted the delete method overload, and implemented pre_delete logic via the following signal handler:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Pages)
def handle_page_delete(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']


    if(obj != None):
        tmp1 = obj.prev_id
        tmp2 = obj.next_id

    if(tmp1 != None):
        tmp1.next_id = tmp2
        obj.prev_id = None

    if(tmp2 != None):
        tmp2.prev_id = tmp1
        obj.next_id = None
```

I followed best practices by putting the handler in a signals sub-module and by registering it via ready() in an overloaded AppConfig in apps.py.

Unfortunately, I still got the same error: ***TypeError delete_model() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given***

I then re-implemented the overloaded delete function as a stub, thinking that maybe I just needed to put the proper options in. So, I kept the signals logic around, and simply added the following back into my Pages model:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Pages, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

You'll note that this time I searched through the documentation, and I put the proper two *args, and **kwargs arguments.

But I still get the same TypeError: ***delete_model() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given***

So finally, I commented out all custom deletion logic whatsoever, and only used the vanilla django codebase. I still get the same error: ***delete_model() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given***

What gives? The exception location is inside my django installation itself, in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`. I've never had problems with the installation before, and I don't *think* I should consider that this is a problem with django itself. I really think I'm the one doing something wrong here, but I'm kind of stuck with no real idea of where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**Edit**

As requested, the Full trace is as follows:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/webcomics/pages/13/delete/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['webcomics.apps.WebcomicsConfig',
 'tinymce',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
  53.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_view
  1718.             self.delete_model(request, obj)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/webcomics/pages/13/delete/
Exception Value: delete_model() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: Is there anything shown in the traceback prior to the error coming from options.py? I mean - you haven't named an attribute in either a model/(model)admin/similar `delete` somewhere or other?

Comment: Can you post the full trace?

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be coming from this code.

Comment: @Escher, Done. @schwobaseggl, I am using django version 1.10.5. @Jon Clements, I could always have missed it, but I did go through the code multiple times looking for stray `delete` keywords, but couldn't find any. :(

Comment: Can you post your admin.py and model definition for that `Pages` model?

Comment: @Escher O.O ... oh, my. And there the problem was all along, staring me in the face. I will post an answer detailing what happened, but the issue was with the admin.py. Thanks for bringing it up, Escher.

Answer (score 0):

everyone. So, yes, I was doing something wrong. Thanks go out to Escher, who suggested that I have a look at my admin.py file. Turns out, there were some duplicate overloaded `delete()` and `delete_model()` methods I had forgotten to, poetically enough, delete. Everything cleared up shortly after I got rid of the duplicates. Jon Clements was right, as well.